# Writing Numeric Data from Javascript to an HTML table cell

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am attempting to do some simple arithmetic to make a sales table via JavaScript and HTML. 
I have each cell of the table containing different id's, based on where I need the numbers to go into the table after the arithmetic is complete. 
My window prompts come up and let me input my data for the "model number" and "quantity sold", but nothing gets filled into the table cells.

Any info would be great, because I am a 100% beginner. 
Thanks all.

I am a beginner so I haven't tried much other than inspecting syntax to ensure I didn't forget a brace or semicolon.

JS Function. (There are 6 total cases, but are identical format)

````````````````````````````````````````````````````
function doMath() {
var mn = Number(window.prompt("Enter the model num", ""));
var qty = Number(window.prompt("Enter the quantity sold", "")) ;
var tot;
switch (mn) {
case 1:
tot = qty*350;
document.getElementById(q1).innerHTML = qty;
document.getElementById(tot1).innerHTML = tot;
break;

case 2:
tot = qty*460;
document.getElementById(q2).innerHTML = qty ;
document.getElementById(tot2).innerHTML = tot;
break;   … … 
``````````````````````````````````````````````````
HTML Table Snippet 
```````````````````````````````````````````````````
<table>
    <tr id="head"> 
        <th> Model # </th> 
        <th> Qty Sold </th> 
        <th> Totals </th> 
    </tr>   
    <tr> 
        <td id="mn1">1</td>
        <td id="q1"></td>
        <td id="tot1"></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>    
        <td id="mn2">2</td>
        <td id="q2"></td>
        <td id="tot2"></td> 
    </tr>   

The goal is to run the function multiple times and update/overwrite any data in the table.
````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add quotation marks (`'` or `"`) around the ID names:

E.g. this line

```
document.getElementById(q1).innerHTML = qty;
```

Should be

```
document.getElementById("q1").innerHTML = qty;
```

And so on.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If it did, please consider marking the answer as accepted. Cheers!